# Will not wake :: Lenovo X1 Yoga running latest updates for Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: suspend, laptop, lenovo, 16.10

I have a Lenovo X1 Yoga running Ubuntu 16.10 which up until a couple of months ago had no problems with suspend/wake on lid close. About 3 months ago it started going sleep on lid close but it flatly refuses to wake on lid open. The only way forward it so hard reboot the machine by holding down the power button.

I'm using the laptop to write this post so I can't tell you exactly what happens when I close the lid ( aka "Goes to sleep; no blinking power light" or  "Goes to sleep; blinking power light" ) but I've noticed that when I come back after having closed the lid some time ago I get:

1) No blinking green power button LED

2) On lid open, I get blinking green power LED but no display backlight, no keyboard input (tried adjusting backlight as a test), and no desktop/password prompt.

3) A short-press of the power LED doesn't change anything. Nor does fiddling with the keyboard and mouse.

I sort of wonder if lack of a blinking light on the power button means the laptop is going into hibernate mode (as opposed to just suspend as it is configured to do) and perhaps that might be part of the problem.

I also have no real idea how to debug this problem because, while their might be some log output during the suspend phase which I could recover after a power rest, I've not been able to find any sort of logs output about failures during the waking process. If its not even attempting to wake..I supposed that makes sense.

So, is anyone else having similar problems? Have any tips for troubleshooting? Have any tips for a fix?

Thx

lshw output follows....

```
atacama
    description: Notebook
    product: 20FQCTO1WW (LENOVO_MT_20FQ_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad X1 Carbon 4th)
    vendor: LENOVO
    version: ThinkPad X1 Carbon 4th
    serial: R90K4GT9
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled chassis=notebook family=ThinkPad X1 Carbon 4th power-on_password=disabled sku=LENOVO_MT_20FQ_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad X1 Carbon 4th uuid=CCC862F8-ED27-B211-A85C-CAB40572AB1B   *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 20FQCTO1WW
       vendor: LENOVO
       physical id: 0
       version: SDK0J40709 WIN
       serial: W1KS638109L
       slot: Not Available
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 3
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 64KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 4
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 64KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:2
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: 5
          slot: L2 Cache
          size: 512KiB
          capacity: 512KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:3
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: 6
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 4MiB
          capacity: 4MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 7
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6600U CPU @ 2.60GHz
          serial: None
          slot: U3E1
          size: 2600MHz
          capacity: 4005MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb intel_pt tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 8
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: Chip LPDDR3 Synchronous 1867 MHz (0.5 ns)
             product: EDFB232A1MA-JD-F
             vendor: Elpida
             physical id: 0
             serial: None
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1867MHz (0.5ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: Chip LPDDR3 Synchronous 1867 MHz (0.5 ns)
             product: EDFB232A1MA-JD-F
             vendor: Elpida
             physical id: 1
             serial: None
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 8GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1867MHz (0.5ns)
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: LENOVO
          physical id: c
          version: N1FET34W (1.08 )
          date: 01/21/2016
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 15MiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 08
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: HD Graphics 520
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 07
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:129 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-generic:0 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Skylake Gaussian Mixture Model
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 8
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f1348000-f1348fff
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: Non-VGA unclassified device
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 13
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f1349000-f1349fff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:122 memory:f1320000-f132ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.8.10-xanmod12 xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.08
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: ThinkPad Compact USB Keyboard with TrackPoint
                   vendor: Lenovo
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 3.30
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@1:7
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Video
                   product: Integrated Camera
                   vendor: 8SSC20F26978L1GZ61404JF
                   physical id: 8
                   bus info: usb@1:8
                   version: 0.11
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:3 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Generic USB device
                   vendor: Validity Sensors, Inc.
                   physical id: 9
                   bus info: usb@1:9
                   version: 1.64
                   serial: 945284c9045f
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:4
                   description: Human interface device
                   product: Pen and multitouch sensor
                   vendor: Wacom Co.,Ltd.
                   physical id: a
                   bus info: usb@1:a
                   version: 0.04
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=400mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.8.10-xanmod12 xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.08
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic:2
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:f134a000-f134afff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:130 memory:f134b000-f134bfff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 memory:f1200000-f12fffff
           *-generic
                description: Unassigned class
                product: RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=rtsx_pci latency=0
                resources: irq:124 memory:f1200000-f1200fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:18 memory:f1100000-f11fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 8260
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: wlp4s0
                version: 3a
                serial: a4:34:d9:bf:a0:18
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.10-xanmod12 firmware=22.361476.0 ip=172.16.10.61 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:132 memory:f1100000-f1101fff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.4
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:f1000000-f10fffff
           *-storage
                description: Non-Volatile memory controller
                product: NVMe SSD Controller
                vendor: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: storage pm msi pciexpress msix nvm_express bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
                resources: irq:16 memory:f1000000-f1003fff ioport:d000(size=256)
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: Sunrise Point-LP PMC
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 21
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f1344000-f1347fff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=64
             resources: irq:131 memory:f1340000-f1343fff memory:f1330000-f133ffff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 21
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f134c000-f134c0ff ioport:efa0(size=32)
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: Ethernet Connection I219-LM
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
             logical name: enp0s31f6
             version: 21
             serial: 54:ee:75:93:92:84
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
             resources: irq:125 memory:f1300000-f131ffff   *-battery
       product: 00HW028
       vendor: LGC
       physical id: 1
       slot: Front
       capacity: 52260mWh
       configuration: voltage=15.2V   *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: dummy0
       serial: e2:0e:50:55:d8:6f
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=dummy driverversion=1.0   *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:fd:e3:d5:62
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes   *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: virbr1
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.42.1 link=no multicast=yes   *-network:3 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 5
       logical name: virbr0-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:4e:db:4a
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s   *-network:4 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 6
       logical name: virbr1-nic
       serial: 52:54:00:fa:6d:93
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s   *-network:5
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 7
       logical name: virbr0
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a Toshiba Satellite Pro C660D which I owned until last week. I tried everything I could think of and also posted on here about it at some point I believe and the consensus was really that there is nothing to be done on the user end; it's more than likely a fault at Canonical's end. I had it working fine back from U12.04 then around a month after I owned it it started happening just as you described and didn't get rectified with several reinstalls of the OS even through 16.04.

I know this isn't much use, but it's just to let you know that if there is a solution to this it is very niche. I believe it only happens to a small assortment of makes and models (such as some of the original models of the Dell XPS laptops).